# Regular expression to validate a URL safe string in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, validation, nsurl, nsregularexpression

In my iPhone application I am constructing a URL by passing some params

as in

```
NSURL * url;
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:Param1];
```

Now I want to validate `Param1` to accept only the URL safe characters, other way around is to encode the URL I agree , but I need to validate the Param1 since it is exposed to the user to change, is there any stright forward native API to do so?, or Regex is the only way? please provide me the Regex if so , Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could encode it

```
NSString *encodedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)
  CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    (__bridge CFStringRef)originalString,
    NULL,
    CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

if (![encodedString isEqualToString:originalString]) {
    // It contains characters that are probably not legal.
}
```

Or you could just check for the characters listed above, but what fun would that be?  :-)

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet
                             characterSetWithCharactersInString:
                                @":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) { ... }
```